# ISO C++ forbids variable length array

Tags: arrays

So this program works perfectly in CodeBlocks, but my schools compiler shows this error. It's probably a simple fix. Can someone make this code work on this c++11 compiler and explain?

```
error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Werror=vla]
         int a[c], b[c];
                ^
error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Werror=vla]
         int a[c], b[c];
                      ^


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,j,l;

    cout<<"Unesite cjelobrojni parametar n: ";
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    if(n==1) cout<<setw(4)<<1;

    else{
        int c(n);
        int a[c], b[c]; //Compiler gives error here

        for(int k=0; k<c; k++) {
            a[0]=1;
            a[k]=0;
        }
        for(i=0; i<c; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<c; j++)
                if(a[j]!=0) 
                    cout<<setw(4)<<a[j];
            cout<<endl;

            for(l=c-1; l>0; l--)
            b[l]=a[l-1]+a[l];
            for(int p=1; p<c; p++) a[p]=b[p];

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: After the array problem, your program has many bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dose use new to create array, you must provide const int.
So, using new to create an dynamic array. As your index is come from run time, you cannot use static memory allocation(Static array), you have to use dynamic memory allocation to create your array in runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j, l;

    cout << "Unesite cjelobrojni parametar n: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 1) cout << setw(4) << 1;

    else{
        int c(n);
        //int a[c], b[c]; //Compiler gives error here
        int* a = new int[c];
        int* b = new int[c];

        for (int k = 0; k<c; k++) {
            a[0] = 1;
            a[k] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i<c; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j<c; j++)
            if (a[j] != 0)
                cout << setw(4) << a[j];
            cout << endl;

            for (l = c - 1; l>0; l--)
                b[l] = a[l - 1] + a[l];
            for (int p = 1; p<c; p++) a[p] = b[p];
            delete[] a, b; //using new should delete by yourself
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it, I just replaced `int a[c], b[c];`

with

```
vector<int>a(c);
vector<int>b(c);
```

and it works great now!

solved